# I can't figure out how to make my loop work and calculate the cumulation of scores

Tags: c++

Class scores Write a program that calculates the total grade for N classroom exercises as a percentage. The user should input the value for N followed by each of the N scores and totals. Calculate the overall percentage (sum of the total points earned divided by the total points possible) and output it as a percentage.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    float s; //score
    float t; //total possible points
    float p; //percentage
    int n; // # of exercises
     cout << "Enter the number of exercises to input: "<<endl;
     cin >> n;
     for (int i=1; i <=n; i++)
     {
        cout << "Enter the score received for Exercise " <<endl;
        cin >> s;
        cout << "Enter the total points possible for Exercise " << endl;
        cin >> t;
        p = (s/t)*100;
    }
    cout << "your total is " << s << " out of "<< t << " or " << p << "%" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

For some reason when I run it, it only calculates the percentage of the last exercise inputted and not the total score and points. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Nothing in the code sums any of the inputs or calculated results. If you want more than the last result computed, you'll have to store the previous results or keep a running total of the previous results.

Comment: *This code resulted on only calculating the percentage of the last score inputted* -- Where do you store the previous inputted values and calculation, so that a total at the end can be computed?  Every loop iteration resets `s`, `t` and `p` to the latest values, so it isn't a surprise you only see the last value computed.

Comment: How do I store previous results or keep a running total?

Comment: How would you do this with a calculator?  If you had to add a series of 10 numbers, you wouldn't hit the "Clear" button after adding two numbers, would you?   That is effectively what your current loop is doing.  You need to *add to* a total that starts at 0.

Comment: Add more variables to hold the totals.

Comment: Create additional variables for the total_score and total_points. Initialize them to 0. Then add the `s` to `total_score` and `p` to `total_points` each iteration.

Comment: Side note: Rather than writing comments to explain the purpose of a variable, bake the purpose into the variables identifier so that the purpose follows the variable around. Eg. instead of `float s; //score`, write `float score;`. Now when the reader of your code has to interpret `cout << "your total is " << s << " out of "<< t << " or " << p << "%" << endl;`, they get `cout << "your total is " << score << " out of "<< t << " or " << p << "%" << endl;` and don't have to look up for the comment to remind themselves what `s` meant.

Comment: Plus it's really easy to mix up two 1-letter variables and the mark 1 human brain is really bad at noticing you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the cumulative score and potential points as you go. *Then* at the completion of the loop you can calculate an average.

Use `double` rather than `float` unless you have a very specific reason not to, and you may wish to use `iomanip` to meaninfully format your floating point values on output.

Note that the variables to hold each score and available points number can be locally scoped to the loop as they are never used afterwards.

```
     double s = 0;
     double p = 0;

     for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
     {
        double s_temp, p_temp;

        cout << "Enter the score received for Exercise " <<endl;
        cin >> s_temp;
        cout << "Enter the total points possible for Exercise " << endl;
        cin >> p_temp;
        s += s_temp;
        p += p_temp;
    }

    double avg = s / p * 100;
```

Now, you may wish to actually store all of the input grade info points. For that you might define a struct to hold both points of information, and then create a `std::vector` of those structs.

```
struct Grade {
    double score;
    double points;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "Number of grades? ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<Grade> grades(n);

    for (auto &g : grades) {
        std::cout << "Enter score: ";
        std::cin >> g.score;

        std::cout << "Out of points: ";
        std::cin >> g.points;
    }

    double total_score, total_points;
    for (const auto &g : grades) {
        total_score += g.score;
        total_points += g.points;
    }

    double avg = total_score / total_points * 100;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You really clarified things for me... I am new at this and feeling overwhelmed. But, you answered very kindly to help my program run... I appreciate it.